# Error in value access

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, jquerymobile

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!pub}" var="a">  
     <apex:column headerValue="Pub-ID">  
      <apex:outputlink value="/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>  
     </apex:column>  
     <apex:column value="{!a.id}" headerValue="Publication SFDC Id"/> 
     <apex:column >
     <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Accept invitation</a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
                  <p>These are the terms and conditions of viewing the publication.
                  </p>
                  <form>
                      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> I agree</input></label>

                        <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="openAction('{!a.ID}')"></input>
                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel"></input>
                  </form>
            </div>
     </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>  
<script>
function openAction(ID)
                             {
                                 alert(ID);
                             }                        
               </script>
```

Now when the `openAction` function is being called the alert is showing only the last value of the 'a' variable and not the value corresponding to the button clicked. Is there any way to pass the name corresponding to the value which is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I pass the object to the function. In the function you can read the value property.

```
<input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="openAction(this);"></input>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"></input>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openAction(a){
        console.log(a);
        console.log($(a).prop('value'));
        console.log($(a).val());
    }
</script>
```